# <?php echo $_GET['s'] ?> get search terms or search keyword

Tags: php

well i wanted ask how to get search 'keyword' or 'terms' using

- Link : /s/hahahahaha
- Search : hahahahaha
- Script : `<?php _e('Search results for', 'customtheme'); ?> "<?php echo $_GET['s'] ?>"`

and its doesnt work here the result Search results for ""

Comment: because your $_GET['s'] is empty.

Comment: yes i know,im asking how to get search keyword?

Comment: dont understand the question. sorry, please reframe

Comment: you know <?php echo $_GET['s'] ?> only working when my search query using domain.com/?s=keyword and now im using search query /s/keyword not ?s=keyword

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like apache mod_rewrite module so the /s/keyword will be rewritten internally to ?s=keyword and you'll get the value with $_GET['s'].

This is called **fancy urls** and I would never do this with php and do it with my http server (apache or nginx) instead.

Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106097/creating-a-fancy-url-with-php).

In your example you could create an .htaccess file (if you are using apache):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ yourphpfile.php?s=$1 [L,NC]
```

replacing *yourphpfile*.php with the filename of your php file.